# IEnumerable vs Ilist - IsNullOrEmpty extension method

Tags: c#, list, extension-methods, ienumerable, isnullorempty

I have a custom collection `IList<user>`as users. When I tried to check whether `users` is null or empty, I did not get any intelligence help(like `IsNullOrEmpty`) so I wrote the below extension method

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
        if (source.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
}
```

To my surprise, I found that `IEnumerable<T>` has `IsNullOrEmpty()`.

As per my knowledge `IList` extends `ICollection` which again extend `IEnumerable`, if that is the case then `IList` should support `IsNullOrEmpty`.

Please correct where I am wrong.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` has not an `IsNullOrEmpty` method, it is the extension that you have written above ;) If you call it you get a  `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: As a side note: `IEnumerable<T>` should *not* be assumed to be repeatable; the only way to test whether a sequence is empty is to start iterating it: if you start iterating it, it may then be dead, done, gone, finished, never to be seen again

Comment: @MarcGravell can you please explain what repeatable means?

Comment: @Tech repatable === you can query the data more than once (and get the same thing); if that data is an open stream on a network socket, for example: you can only read it once - once you've read it: *it is gone*. Another trivial example would be: I can write an `IEnumerable<T>` that yields random numbers based on a crypto seed: completely non-repeatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` has not an `IsNullOrEmpty` method, it is the extension that you have written above. If you call it you get a  `StackOverflowException`.

You could implement it in this way:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source == null || !source.Any();
}
```

But it's important to note that this method is not so helpful and can even improve for the worse. Because `Enumerable.Any` will "consume" the query. So if it's not an in-memory collection it has to call `GetEnumerator` and start enumerating it so check if there is at least one item. Sometimes the object will be diosposed in case it was enumerated (like in `File.ReadLines` in .NET <= 4) which willl cause an `ObjectDisposedException` if you try to consume it later again.

Another example when this method has unwanted side-effects is when the sequence is a query which filters(`...Where(x => Compute(x, random.Next()))`). This query    might yield different results everytime. To quote Marc Gravell's comment: "*IEnumerable should not be assumed to be repeatable*".

In Linq-To-Sql or Linq-To-Entities you'd call the database on every `IsNullOrEmpty` call.

Answer (score 0):

As @Marc Gravel mentioned in the comments "`IEnumerable<T>` should not be assumed to be repeatable". Suppose that your source `IEnumerable` is created from a datareader. You only have one chance to iterate it. If you consume that only chance just to see if it is empty, you will not be able to access the records again. Maybe you would like to write an extension method(if needed) for `IList`, not for `IEnumerable`.

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IList<T> source)
{
    return source == null || source.Count == 0;
}
```

Comment: I wish C# and VB.NET had "foreach" constructs that could accept things patterned on enumerators, rather than only being able to accept things with a `GetEnumerator` method.  Things which can only be read once should be enumerators rather than enumerables.  It's due to language's inability to work with the former that they have to pretend to be the latter.